# beagleboard com and HDMI dispaly

Tags: ubuntu, gdm, serial-console

I've installed Ubuntu 11.10,lkde and gem on my BB and I connect to it through serial com. when trying GUI application through the com (e.g. gedit) I get "display not found, though a monitor is connected to the HDMI output. Is it possible to pass display from the serial terminal to the HDMI output?

Comment: When I had a beagleboard and a touch shield the stock image didn't work because it didn't understand the shield was preferred out.  I'm guessing something similar is going on.  Look at your image/boot configuration would be my guess(to get serial working not to pass it to hdmi).

Comment: When I open a console through the HDMI everything works perefectly, the problem is when I try to open it from the serial console...

Comment: That's sort of what I was talking about.